# Using isdigit() in Python to count integers together and present it using a word in a dictionary

Tags: python

My problem is as follows:
I have a file which contains words and numbers (like a financial statement with years as numbers) called `text.txt`

I need to calculate the frequency of all words in the text, save the words and counts as key-value pairs in a dictionary (called `counts`), and print the dictionary. And I must write the code such that all digits are counted together and presented using the word `'numberdigit'` by using the `isdigit()` method.

```
counts = {}

for word in text_adj:
    if word not in counts:
        counts[word] = 1
    else:
        counts[word] = counts[word] + 1
        
print(counts)
```

This code gives output like this, which unfortunately counts numbers:

```
{'item': 34, '7': 19, 'management’s': 6, 'discussion': 11, 'and': 376, 
 'analysis': 6, 'of': 273, 'financial': 51, 'condition': 4, 'results': 14, 
 'operations': 17, 'the': 292, 'following': 7, '“mda”': 1, 'is': 57, 
 'intended': 2, 'to': 221, 'help': 4, 'reader': 1, 'understand': 1, 
 'microsoft': 4, 'corporation': 1, 'mda': 3, 'provided': 3, 
 'as': 36, 'a': 97, 'supplement': 1}
```

I have tried using multiple variations of `if`, `if not` and `==` statements with `isdigit`, but all efforts failed.

Comment: You should make a [mcve] that includes example inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: You can have `counts['numbers']` which would increase if `word.isdigit()` and act normally if `word` is not a number with `if / else` statements. You can also use `set(text_adj)` to remove the need of checking if `word` is not in `counts`.

Comment: Take a look at the *Counter* class in the *collections* module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `isdigit()` returns true when the input is a digit, this code should work.

```
counts = {}
counts["numberdigit"] = 0
for word in text_adj:
    if word.isdigit():
       counts["numberdigit"] += 1
    elif word not in counts:
       counts[word] = 1
    else:
       counts[word] = counts[word] + 1
    
print(counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a tiny bit shorter code from [Christopher Holley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72104060/8564999)

```
counts = {}

for word in text_adj:
    if word.isdigit():
        word = 'numberdigit'
    counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1
```

Comment: Adding a row you could go for `import collections.defaultdict` to clean it up even more :) . `counts = collections.defaultdict(int)` and `counts[word] += 1`

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(map(lambda x: "numberdigit" if x.isdigit() else x, text_adj))

print(counts)
```

You will probably get by with this. Read up on the `collections.Counter` documentation. It got some neat features you might find nifty like `.most_common()`

`map` apply the `lambda` (anonyms function, the if else test) to all words (strings) in the iterable `text_adj`.